# Using iCloud with Core Data conflict

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, core-data, icloud

I'm using iCloud with Core Data to sync data between two devices but the problem is when data is merged on the same time as i'm editing the same NSManagedObject on the other device, the app crash while refetching data using NSFetchedResultsController (the app crash on performFetch), but in the other case where i am not opening the NSManagedObject, it works fine.

```
[[[ZTManagerObject shared] context] mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error while fetching data %@; %@", [error localizedDescription], error);
    abort();
}
```

Comment: And what message do you get when the app crashes? It's a crucial detail, don't leave it out.

Comment: Check you are running on the right thread.